# How to store the data from pen drive

Tags: android

Thanks for previous reply
I am new to android development. I just trying to develop a simple app. is it possible to retrieve data from pen drive to SD card through tablet. my table have provision to connect the pen drive facility, i want to get the data from the pen drive and store it in sd card. is this possible. pls rectify if i made any mistake.

Comment: Your question is not focused enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy or move files from an USB drive, or micro-SD card, to the internal memory of the tablet and vice-versa, a so-called file manager is needed. As Android does not include it, you can use free file managers such as Astro File Manager, OI File Manager or Linda File Manager, available on the Android Market. Installing such an application will allow you to check the content of the storage devices directly.

Refer:
http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9661/~/copying-files-from-usb-storage-and-micro-sd-card-to-the-tablet